# Simulate ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE in SQLITE Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to find a way to get `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` from MySQL working in SQLite.
The problem is that my current attempts are always failing due to the fact, that SQLite always deletes the row first and inserts it with the new values and the same primary key. When I now have a foreign key constraint `ON DELETE CASCADE` on this primary key in another table, the entries in the other tables always get deleted.

What I've tried:

```
db.insertWithOnConflict(tableName, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
db.replace(tableName, null, values);
```

Both methods first remove the entry and re-insert it.

Is there any method to prevent this kind of behaviour and just update the entry's values, except for the primary?

---

My implementation based on the answer:

```
public long insertUpdate(int id, ContentValues values) {
    if (!isOpen()) {
        open();
    }


    ContentValues valuesToInsert = new ContentValues();
    valuesToInsert.putAll(values);
    valuesToInsert.put(indexKey, id);
    long result = db.insertWithOnConflict(tableName, null, valuesToInsert, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
    if (result == id) {
        update(id, values);
    }

    return id;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never tried it before, but could you first attempt to call `insertWithOnConflict()` with a `CONFLICT_FAIL` parameter and then, if it returns with a [failed id code](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertWithOnConflict(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20int)), then run an `update()` for the same position?

```
int result = insertWithOnConflict(YourDbHelperClass.tableName, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_FAIL);
if (result == -1) update(tableName, values, YourDbHelperClass.rowId + "=?", new String[] { "x" }); //x being row number
```

Just a thought.

Comment: Yeah that could work, I got to try it. Sadly this will execute 2 queries instead of 1.

Comment: @Chris, what do you think MySql does when you send to the DB a `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` query? Let me tell you: a insert and a update. So yeah, insertWithOnConflict is what you want. :)

Comment: All right, I edited my implementation in my question.